# add values next to percentage of total in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new user of Tableau and I have a question:

How can I present **both** the values and the percentage of total in stacked column in tableau?

here is example how it should look like (i know how to do it in excel but not in Tableau):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Construct a function that generates the string you want to appear as a label and use that in the label tray.

Answer (score 0):

Just add both values to label. After you compute the percent of total on SUM(Teus) **hold down control** to make a copy and drag it to Label to explicitly have it displayed. Then drag a new SUM(Teus) from the data pane onto Label as well. Now you will be able to see both values. You can then click on the Label button and then the [...] button if you want to customize how these values are displayed. Side note: you are getting those skinny bars because you have Year as a continuous dimension. Using it as a discrete dimension will give you the thick bars.
[image]